# QStandardItemModel itemChanged not called

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qstandarditemmodel

Using QStandardItemModel in a QTreeView, itemChanged signals are not triggered (for example on rename). If I recall correctly this was functioning in a much earlier PyQt5 version.

```
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.resize(200, 100)
        self.dataTree = QTreeView(self)
        self.dataTree.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.dataTree.resize(200, 100)
        self.dataModel = QStandardItemModel(self.dataTree)
        self.dataModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Sources'])
        self.dataModelParent = self.dataModel.invisibleRootItem()
        self.dataTree.setModel(self.dataModel)
        self.dataModel.itemChanged.connect(lambda: self.itemChanged)

        master = QStandardItem('test1')
        self.dataModel.appendRow(master)
        
    @pyqtSlot(QStandardItem)
    def itemChanged(self, item):
        print('Item Changed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = QMainWindow()
    Main = Main()
    Main.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Note, creating a global variable that has the same name of a class is a terrible idea, since you're overwriting that name and so losing the reference to it.

Comment: It was only used for the MRE but bad practice nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the line...

```
self.dataModel.itemChanged.connect(lambda: self.itemChanged)
```

Here, your lambda doesn't actually do anything.  Instead you need something like...

```
self.dataModel.itemChanged.connect(lambda item: self.itemChanged(item))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll add myself to the brain transplant list.

Comment: Actually, the lambda is just useless, since the argument is the same for the target function, so: `self.dataModel.itemChanged.connect(self.itemChanged)`

Comment: @musicamante Actually, I did try that but it resulted in the error `TypeError: connect() failed between itemChanged(QStandardItem*) and itemChanged()` which I don't quite understand.  I didn't have time to look at it any further and, hence, decided to omit it from my answer.

Comment: @G.M. that is probably a bug, but can be easily solved: remove the slot decorator, or use the string syntax *including* the asterisk for the pointer (`pyqtSlot('QStandardItem*')`).

Comment: `'QStandardItem*'` is strange in python.

Comment: @misantroop that's because it's C++.

Comment: @musicamante is it  @pyqtSlot('QStandardItem*') ??? or just pyqtSlot('QStandardItem*') ???

Comment: @pippo1980 the `@` is required, otherwise it wouldn't work as a decorator.

Comment: @musicamante thanks was just being overcautious to be sure I was getting it